# AWS S3 Bucket Policy principal with iam role

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, policy, bucket

I can add IAM Role as principal for bucket policy from AWS console.

I cannot do the same from Java API. When I have added IAM Role to the principal of bucket policy and perform api operation. I am getting below error.

```
Invalid principal in policy Service: Amazon S3
```

Code:

```
client.setBucketPolicy(BUCKET_NAME,
    new Policy().withStatements(new Statement(Effect.Allow)
                                            .withActions(S3Actions.GetObject, S3Actions.PutObject, S3Actions.GetObjectAcl)
                                            .withPrincipals(new Principal("AWS", "arn:aws:iam::12345678:role/ECR-ROLE"))
                                            .withResources(new S3ObjectResource(BUCKET_NAME, "*"))).toJson());
```

Comment: The console uses the same API as the SDKs so it's strange to see different behavior.  Your policy in both cases is **identical**?

Comment: Yes, both policies are identical. I have updated my question with code sample i am using.